# jQuery or CSS Animation causing Images to Blur

Tags: html, css, css-animations, pageload

I'm working on a bug in a website that is causing my images to blur on page load. I can't seem to find any similar cases in this or other forums. The images appear, but are blurry/pixelated as the page loads then, they become clear. I have a CSS3 "gears animation" that uses "-webkit-animation" and it executes for 2000 milliseconds on pageload, and immediately after the animation stops, the images throughout the site become clear. Does anyone have an idea what might be the cause of this? This occurs on all image types (vectors, pngs, jpgs...). Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Any code to share???

Comment: I've see css animations cause strange artifacts with text and images before. Not sure I'd say I've seen blurring. If you can post code that will recreate the issue here on in a fiddle that would help.

Comment: I've tried to create a fiddle to replicate my issue, but I don't experience the blurring when I strip everything else out. There must be something else causing this issue. Here's the fiddle anyway: http://jsfiddle.net/g4eg7d19/8/

Comment: I would think it might be a coincidence that the images become clear when the animation stops, but when I remove the gears completely, the blurring doesn't occur.

Comment: Also, I am adding/removing a sidebar on a button click event. On every click, the blur occurs for about 1-2 seconds for every image on the page.

Comment: Do you have a live site with it?

Comment: @ZachSaucier unfortunately I don't. :/

Comment: My boss believes it is a redrawing issue. Does this seem like a possibility?